# Exponential growth/decay formula: what happened to the other constant of integration?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

The standard equation for exponential growth and decay starts and is derived like this:

$$ {dP\over dt}=kP$$

$$ {dP\over P}=kdt$$

$$ \int{dP\over P}=\int kdt$$

$$ \color{red}{\ln |P|}=kt+C$$

I don't understand the left hand side at this point, isn't $\int{1\over x}dx = \ln |x| +C$? Where did the constant of integration from the left integral go?

Comment: Well if you mean that it should be $\ln |P| + K_1 = kt + K_2$, then call $C=K_2-k_1$ and that is

Comment: The constant on the right hand side was integrated into the constant on the left hand side. Or is it the other way around? I can never differentiate left from right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you integrate both sides, each has a constant - you'd get, for constants $A,B$:

$$ \int{dP\over P}=\int kdt \implies \ln|P|+A = kt+B$$

Well, we can subtract $A$ from both sides and define a constant $C = B-A$; then

$$\ln|P|+A = kt+B \implies \ln|P|=kt+B-A=kt+C$$

This combination of constants is often implicit in solving differential equations - you'll integrate on two sides and then just combine the constants on whichever side of the equation is more convenient.

Answer (score 5):

Well, notice that:

$$\ln\left|\text{P}\left(t\right)\right|+\text{C}_1=\text{k}\cdot t+\text{C}_2\tag1$$

Getting $\text{C}_1$ on the other side gives:

$$\ln\left|\text{P}\left(t\right)\right|=\text{k}\cdot t+\text{C}_2-\text{C}_1\tag2$$

But $\text{C}_2-\text{C}_1$ is another constant, so:
$$\ln\left|\text{P}\left(t\right)\right|=\text{k}\cdot t+\text{C}\tag3$$